# JSON with JAXB and Jersey and Inheritance

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I am currently trying to serialize some complex objects to JSON using JAXB. I use Jersey as a REST framework with the following configuration class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/customerManagement")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public PartyLocationManagementApplication() {
        register(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
    }
}
```

I have set up the following classes:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({
        AbstractListRTO.class,
        AbstractDataRTO.class
})
public class RestTransferObject {
    private Link self;
    public Link getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(Link self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
}

@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({CustomersRTO.class})
public abstract class AbstractListRTO<T extends RestTransferObject>
extends RestTransferObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    private Collection<T> elements;
    public Collection<T> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    public void setElements(Collection<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomersRTO extends AbstractListRTO<CustomerRTO> {

    public CustomersRTO(Collection<CustomerRTO> customers) {
        super.setElements(customers);
    }
    public CustomersRTO() {
    }
    public Collection<CustomerRTO> getCustomers() {
        return getElements();
    }
    public void setCustomers(Collection<CustomerRTO> customers) {
        setElements(customers);
    }
}

@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({CustomerRTO.class})
public abstract class AbstractDataRTO extends RestTransferObject {
    private Integer no;
    public AbstractDataRTO() {
    }
    public Integer getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setNo(Integer no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomerRTO extends AbstractDataRTO {

    public CustomerRTO() {
    }
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Currently I get the following JSON output:

```
{
"@type": "customersRTO",
"element": [
    {
        "@type": "abstractDataRTO",
        "self": {
            "href": "http://somelink/1"
        },
        "no": 1
    },
    {
        "@type": "abstractDataRTO",
        "self": {
            "href": "http://somelink/1"
        },
        "no": 2
    }
]
}
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
{
"@type": "customersRTO",
"element": [
    {
        "@type": "customerRTO",
        "self": {
            "href": "http://somelink/1"
        },
        "no": 1,
        "name": "Jon"
    },
    {
        "@type": "customerRTO",
        "self": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://somelink/1"
        },
        "no": 2,
        "name": "Jane"
    }
]
}
```

As one can see, fields @type has different values and field name is missing. I made sure that I add CustomerRTO to the list of customersRTO. If I request the xml representation every thing works fine, but as soon as I try to request the JSON representation every thing goes wrong.

Comment: I've often experienced the symptom that the XML and the JSON representation using MOXy differ when MOXy wasn't set up correctly to be the JAXB JSON provider. Two possible problems, do you have the jaxb.properties file in one of your packages? Or if you do, are your classes in different packages? See http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html